# WPF Buttons below ListView - disappear when ListView too big

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView where the user can add files. There are two buttons below the
ListView for adding a single file, or a whole directory of files. The code structure is similar to this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView>...</ListView>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add Scan"/>
        <Button Content="Add mulit"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This works well until the number of files exceeds the available space:

[image]

However, when there are more files than available space, a scrollbar appears for the TreeView, but the stackpanel with the buttons disappears:

[image]

I guess the problem is that the StackPanel which contains the TreeView and the other StackPanel allows child elements to grow outside available size. If I replace the StackPanel with a grid, I get the desired behavior when there are many files, but when there are fewer files (or none at all), the buttons are stuck at the bottom:

[image]

Any idea on which combination of panels I can use to let the StackPanel with the two buttons be right below the TreeView, unless the TreeView takes up all space, in which case I would like the buttons be visible at the bottom of the window, and the TreeView to have a scrollbar.

Comment: please include the TreeView in your Code example: all 2 answers work for me with the posted code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to occupy the entire space below the list/tree, then try this:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:SubstractorConverter x:Key="SubstractorConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.MaxHeight>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SubstractorConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="MainGrid" />
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Footer" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ListView.MaxHeight>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Name="Footer">
            <Button Content="Add Scan"/>
            <Button Content="Add mulit"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestWpf
{
    class SubstractorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dbls = values.OfType<double>().ToArray();
            if (dbls.Length != 2)
                return null;

            return dbls[0] - dbls[1];
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The result of this code can be seen in the last picture of my post (where I have used a grid instead of a StackPanel). When there are no file paths in the TreeView, I do not want it to take up a lot of empty space, and the buttons should be right below the TreeView.

Comment: @Chepe I've just added that too.

Comment: A converter w/ ActualHeight is total overkill for this.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling I didn't find a better solution though, even if it's an overkill. The other one (with two Auto-s) simply doesn't do what's expected.

Comment: @armenm Thanks for answering :) I tried you suggestion with the ValueConverter, however, the Convert method is only called on startup or when resizing the window. So when adding more elements to the ListView so that it grows, it continues to grow outside the window bounds.

Comment: @Chepe I've just tested it and it works correctly. In my case the grid is directly nested into a window. What is your entire construction?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have several Grids in my window, and the Grid/StackPanel is nested inside two Grids. Is your converter being called when you change the number of elements in the TreeView without resizing the window?

Comment: Yes, it's updated correctly, whatever you do - resize/add/remove items dynamically.

Comment: @armenm you should remove your 2 first sugestions so your answer gets more clear

Comment: @armenm I simplified my structure, and you are correct, then it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer - only left the last one.